# 3 unknown coefficients in my recursion formula?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, recursion

I am solving this second order ODE:

$$-gdf''+(-w^2 + iw^2(mx+b))f(x)=0$$

I used power series expansion about $x=0$. Assuming $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, and $f''(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$ and substituting these to the ODE, I arrived at the following:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} -gd n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} w^2 a_n x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} iw^2 ma_nx^{n+1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} iw^2ba_nx^n = 0 $$

Now, expressing everything in terms of $x^n$ I got:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -gd(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} w^2 a_n x^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} iw^2 ma_{n-1}x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} iw^2ba_nx^n = 0$$

Changing the lower index to $n=1$:

$$-2gda_2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} -gd(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n - w^2a_0 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} w^2 a_n x^n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} iw^2ma_{n-1}x^n + iw^2ba_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} iw^2ba_n x^n = 0$$

Equating all coefficients to $0$ we have:

$$-2gda_2 - gd(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} - w^2a_0 - w^2a_n + iw^2ma_{n-1} + iw^2ba_0 + iw^2ba_n = 0$$

Since $-2gd, -w^2, iw^2 \neq 0$, then $a_2, a_0 = 0$ (is this correct?), so the equation above reduces to:

$$ -gd(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} + (-w^2 + iw^2b)a_n + iw^2ma_{n-1} = 0$$

which is now my recursion formula but involves 3 unknowns $(a_{n+2}, a_n,$ and $a_{n-1})$. Any help or tips to proceed?

Comment: Note that `\sum_{n = 0} ^N` renders so much better than writing `\Sigma_{n=0} ^N`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! @SeanRoberson

Answer (score 1):

First think that $a_k\in \mathbb{C}$. Reserve $a_0, a_1$ for four real initial conditions and then proceed

$$
a_{k+2} = \frac{(ib-1)w^2 a_k+im w^2 a_{k-1}}{gd(k+2)(k+1)}
$$

Comment: how did $a_{k+2}$ become $a_{k+1}$, or is that a typo error? and does it mean that I'll fix $a_0, a_1$ as arbitrary constants, and then solve for $a_2, a_3, ...$ using the formula you wrote above? Thank you so much!

Comment: I wrote $a_{k+1}$ instead of $a_{k+2}$! My bad! Thanks.

Comment: A second order ode needs two complex conditions. If those are initial conditions, then we can leave $a_0,a_1$ for this purpose.

Comment: how about the "for four real initial conditions" part, what do you mean by that?

Comment: If the ode is complex, (it seems to have $i$ in it's  definition) then given $a_0 = {a_0}_r + i {a_0}_i$ and $a_1 = {a_1}_r + i {a_1}_i$ we count four real numbers to define $({a_0}_r,{a_0}_i,{a_1}_r, {a_1}_i)$